# Static ressources: where define context aliases with tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, resources, aliases

I am looking for a way to access static resources (e.g. video files) from my web app JEE.

In my local environment, I added an aliases attribute in the context of my webapp under the config of my tomcat server in Eclipse. This works verywell.
Doing that my context in Eclipse Tomcat server.xml is:

```
<Context path="/maWebApp" docBase="path/vers/ma/webApp" aliases="/video=/chemin/sur/mon/PC">
```

Now I want to do the same thing in my production server. But:

- under this server (linux, tomcat7), the file etc/tomcat7/server.xml doesn't contains any "Context" for my webapp. I suppose that the context is created automatically during webApp deployment
- if I add a "Context" for my application, in order to define the "aliase" attribute, my server tomcat doesn't restart anymore.

So my question is: where should I define the "aliase" attribute when I use Tomcat7 and when I deploy my application with .war generated from Eclipse.

Important note: I don't want to manage the aliases in the webapp, because the aliases change depending on the server (local dev or prod).

Thank you very much for any advise and best practise,

Have a good day!

Adrien

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a context attribute to your server.xml.

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/context.html

  > <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">   
  >   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"
  >   SSLEngine="on" />            <Listener
  >   className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"
  >   />   <Listener
  >   className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"
  >   />
  >
  > <Context path="/maWebApp" docBase="path/vers/ma/webApp"
  >   aliases="/video=/chemin/sur/mon/PC" />
  >   </Server>

My tomcat is starting fine with this.

What error do you have when starting it with the "< Context .. />" attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Defining Context elements in server.xml is discouraged. Instead put `context.xml` in

```
$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/
```

`enginename` will most likely be `Catalina`, so e.g if your tomcat directory is `/opt/tomcat7/` and your hostname is `www.mysite.com` then put the context in this directory:

```
/opt/tomcat7/conf/Catalina/www.mysite.com
```

And rename your context file `maWebApp.xml`

**Update**: Unless you need the static resources to be available to your app, and if only you need a virtual directory for visitors to access static resources you do not need the `aliases` attribute. Create a context in a file named `video.xml` in the same directory as above:

```
<Context docBase="/chemin/sur/mon/PC/" path="/video/"></Context>
```

Static resources will then be available at `www.mysite.com/video`